# table html with tree rows in the second line

Tags: html

i want a table with this structure, is there any way to achieve this

```html
<table>
<tr>
    <th> one head line </th> 
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>A</td>
    <td>B</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>C</td>
    <td>D</td>
<td>E</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: What structure? Achieve what? Your question isn't clear

Comment: I think [`colspan`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/td#attr-colspan) is the attribute you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your desired result it can be either

```
<table>
<tr>
    <th colspan="3"> one head line </th> 
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>A</td>
    <td colspan="2">B</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>C</td>
    <td>D</td>
    <td>E</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

or

```
<table>
<tr>
    <th colspan="3"> one head line </th> 
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="2">A</td>
    <td>B</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>C</td>
    <td>D</td>
    <td>E</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: many thanks sir, it was the first solution that i was lookign for

Answer (score 0):

colspan is the attribute used to tell the cell how many columns to span. Assuming you want it to span 3 columns you'd change your code as follows:

```
<table>
<tr>
    <th colspan="3"> one head line </th> 
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>A</td>
    <td>B</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>C</td>
    <td>D</td>
    <td>E</td>
</tr>
</table>
```